# How to convert DataFrame to single row list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert DataFrames in file "text.txt" that contain 101 rows × 1 columns into 1 rows x 1 columns with separator (',')

I tried this code :

```
tweets_data = []
with open("text.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for tweet in f:
        ayu = tweet.rstrip('\n').split(',')
        print(ayu)
```

I expected the output    `[{'text'},{'text'},....,{'text'}]`

but the actual output is

```
[{'text\n'},

 {'text\n'},

 ...

 {'text\n'},]
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the solution would be something like this:

```
with open("fileName.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    listOfTweets = []
    for tweet in f:
        listOfTweets.append(tweet)
    print(listOfTweets)
```